# Need to modify existing CSS3 Org Chart with a second main-level

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with creating/duplicating the first level (director) box with a vertical line between. The Original chart has only One level with sub's below.

See included picture for desired result...[image: Org chart with desired result.]

CodePen link to original org chart :
    http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE

Here's the CSS :

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Generic styling */

body{
    background: #F5EEC9;    
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1142px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

a:focus{
    outline: 2px dashed #f7f7f7;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .content{
        padding: 0 20px;
    }   
}

ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;       
}

ul a{
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all linear .1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .1s;
    transition: all linear .1s;
}


@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    ul a{
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}


ul a span{
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.7em;
    display: block;
}

/*

 */

.administration > li > a{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.director > li > a{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
}

.subdirector:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 130px;
    background: red;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    left: 45.45%;
    position: relative;
}

.subdirector,
.departments{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child,
.departments > li:first-child{  
    width: 18.59894921190893%;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0 auto 92px auto;       
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    z-index: 1; 
}

.subdirector > li:first-child{
    float: right;
    right: 27.2%;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
}

.departments > li:first-child{  
    float: left;
    left: 27.2%;
    border-right: 4px solid white;  
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a,
.departments > li:first-child a{
    width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a{    
    left: 25px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .subdirector > li:first-child,
    .departments > li:first-child{
        width: 40%; 
    }

    .subdirector > li:first-child{
        right: 10%;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }

    .subdirector:after{
        left: 49.8%;
    }

    .departments > li:first-child{
        left: 10%;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
}


.departments > li:first-child a{
    right: 25px;
}

.department:first-child,
.departments li:nth-child(2){
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: left;    
}

.departments:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 81.1%;
    height: 22px;   
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 130px;
    left: 9.1%
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .departments:after{
        border-right: none;
        left: 0;
        width: 49.8%;
    }  
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px){
    .department:first-child:before,
   .department:last-child:before{
    border:none;
  }
}

.department:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 22px;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -22px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

.department{
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    width: 18.59894921190893%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.751313485113835%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.lt-ie8 .department{
    width: 18.25%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .department{
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .department:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 60px;
        border-left: 4px solid white;
        z-index: 1;
        top: -60px;
        left: 0%;
        margin-left: -4px;
    }

    .department:nth-child(2):before{
        display: none;
    }
}

.department > a{
    margin: 0 0 -26px -4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.department > a:hover{  
    height: 80px;
}

.department > ul{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.department li{ 
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    height: 80px;   
}

.department li a{
    background: #fff;
    top: 48px;  
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: -1px;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)))!important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 );
}

.department li a:hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    height: 80px;
    width: 95%;
    top: 39px;
    background-image: none!important;
}

/* Department/ section colors */
.department.dep-a a{ background: #FFD600; }
.department.dep-b a{ background: #AAD4E7; }
.department.dep-c a{ background: #FDB0FD; }
.department.dep-d a{ background: #A3A2A2; }
.department.dep-e a{ background: #f0f0f0; }
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Responsive Organization Chart</h1>
  <figure class="org-chart cf">
    <ul class="administration">
      <li>                  
        <ul class="director">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Director</span></a>
            <ul class="subdirector">
              <li><a href="#"><span>Assistante Director</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="departments cf">                             
              <li><a href="#"><span>Administration</span></a></li>

              <li class="department dep-a">
                <a href="#"><span>Department A</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A5</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-b">
                <a href="#"><span>Department B</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-c">
                <a href="#"><span>Department C</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-d">
                <a href="#"><span>Department D</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D5</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D6</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-e">
                <a href="#"><span>Department E</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>   
      </li>
    </ul>           
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some css

```
.firstDirect{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.firstDirect:after{
      border-left: 4px solid white;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

check the **[demo file here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emQorx)**

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy !.. Perfect solution !.. *thumbs up*